# Gitlab CI - registry and nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to setup self hosted gitlab CI with its own registry. I am also using self signed certificates for TLS, signed this certificate using my own CA, which is installed as a trusted CA in my host machine

Gitlab-CE 13.6.3 version is installed on Ubuntu 18.04. Have installed snap microk8s cluster on the same host

**Questions (some very basics)**

- Does Gitlab registry use the docker daemon ?
- How is the connectivity achieved

  Docker client --> NGINX (5050) -->  Gitlab registry (5000)
- I have below configuration in gitlab.rb file

```
registry['enable'] = true
registry['registry_http_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:5000"
registry['log_directory'] = "/var/log/gitlab/registry"
registry['env'] = {
  'SSL_CERT_DIR' => "/etc/gitlab/ssl"
}

# Below you can find settings that are exclusive to "Registry NGINX"
registry_nginx['enable'] = true
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.local.crt"
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.local.key"

registry_nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
 "Host" => "$http_host",
 "X-Real-IP" => "$remote_addr",
 "X-Forwarded-For" => "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for",
 "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
 "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
}

# When the registry is automatically enabled using the same domain as `external_url`,
# it listens on this port
registry_nginx['listen_port'] = 5050
registry_nginx['listen_addresses'] = ['*', '[::]']
```

When I try to docker login, following errors are observed. Is it expected based on the above configuration ?

```
   - with URL: https://127.0.0.1:5000 - > Login Success
   - with URL: https://127.0.0.1:5050 - > Login Success 
   - with URL: https://gitlab.local:5050 - > x509 certificate signed by unknown authority
```

- I have gitlab k8s & docker runners, Can they access the gitlab registry (nginx) port 5050 from within the container ?

```
    [[runners]]
      name = "docker"
      token = "xxxxxxx"
      executor = "docker"
      [runners.docker]
        image = "docker:stable"
        privileged = true
        volumes = ["/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
```

Note: I tried various gitlab forums/posts about the certificate issues on gitlab registry to build/push images, but to no success

Thank  you

Answer (score 1):

Try by placing the certificate in docker by:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/gitlab.local:5050
cp /yourcerts/gitlab.local.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/gitlab.local:5050/ca.crt
sudo service docker reload
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Yes - I did try that and the ca certificate is in that directory

Comment: I am using registry with self signed certificate but in separate container, gitlab-runner & gitlab all three on same host. I was facing this and resolve using this and also adding the certificate to gitlab container by adding the certificate & key in /etc/gitlab/ssl & adding the registry certificate also in /etc/gitlab/trusted-certs/ try this.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, as posting in gitlab forum/docker forums did not attract that many voices :) . I copied the ca.crt inside - /etc/gitlab/ssl/, /etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.local:5050/, /etc/gitlab/trusted-certs/. Is it possible for you to share the gitlab.rb and config.toml you used to have a cross check ?

Comment: As i am using external registry not the gitlab provided one i didn't change much in gitlab.rb. Only edited this two options  registry_external_url 'https://registry.local:5000' & gitlab_rails['registry_api_url'] = "https://registry.local:5000". And modified the config as above & else is commented by default provided by gitlab.

Comment: Are you using a public external registry or other self hosted registry - microk8s, docker ?

Comment: self hosted registryhttps://hub.docker.com/_/registry image

Comment: I also abandoned the use of gitlab's own registry. Instead I used the microk8s registry and setup unsecure registry. Finally it works. Still could not figure out what I was doing wrong with gitlab managed repo. Thank You for your valuable feedback

Comment: It'k mine too take at-least 4 days to figure out what causing that issue also tried creating issue over gitlab, finally by going through all gitlab docs, registry docs again & gitlab different logs solve using above method.